# Problema al recoger datos mediante post en android studio

Tags: php, email, post, volley

Me gustaría recoger un "email" (dato) y que con este dato en una query traiga de vuelta los datos de una tabla. Una vez regidos los datos, se mostrarían al usuario en unos "textViews", pero no consigo encontrar una solución a esto.

Estoy usando Volley y php para el webservice.

El código del php es el siguiente:

```
<?php

include "connection.php";

//Variables para el envío de email y password.
$email = $_POST['email'];

//Se coloca la sentencia preparada y se ejecuta después.
$statement = $connection -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email = ?");
$statement -> bind_param("s", $email);
$statement -> execute();

//Se obtienen todos los datos de la sentencia.
$result = $statement -> get_result();

//Condicional para validar.
if ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    echo json_encode($row,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}

$statement -> close();
$connection -> close();
?>
```

Y el código en Android Studio es este:

```
public class profileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView user, email, city, town, telephone;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        user = findViewById(R.id.textViewUser);
        email = findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        city = findViewById(R.id.textViewCity);
        town = findViewById(R.id.textViewTown);
        telephone = findViewById(R.id.textViewTelephone);
        getProfile("http://miIp/buksu/getProfile.php");
    }
    private void getProfile(String URL) {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        user.setText(jsonObject.getString("nick"));
                        email.setText(jsonObject.getString("email"));
                        city.setText(jsonObject.getString("city"));
                        town.setText(jsonObject.getString("town"));
                        telephone.setText(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected  Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                param.put("email","prueba1@gmail.com");
                return param;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

He probado a poner "Request.Method.POST" como parámetro, pero me pone en rojo prácticamente todo. Tal como está el código no indica error, salvo el siguiente.

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Podríais ayudarme? Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hola, por favor ayúdanos poniendo qué se supone que te está regresando tu servicio web con php y qué tipo de respuesta es, es decir, si estás retornando un objeto json o simplemente un string. En base a esto, podemos darle una solución a cómo recibirlo y trabajarlo con volley y meterlo en los textviews que mencionas.

Comment: Los errores de tipo *`... value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`* ocurren **cuando hay salidas por pantalla que no son parte del JSON**. Tienes que controlar muy bien eso en el servidor. Revisa que no sale por pantalla en el archivo `connection.php` y revisa tu archivo PHP que no tenga caracteres BOM  ocultos y demás, con una simpleza como esa tu JSON se daña y ocurren ese tipo de errores. Otro asunto es aclararse con el método, si es `POST` tienes que configurar de forma distinta y pasar los datos en los header. Si es `GET` los pasas en la URL.

Comment: Comprobaré todo esto. Por ahora, lo he realizado todo de otra forma y funciona. Cuando termine lo que estoy haciendo compruebo lo que habéis puesto. Muchísimas gracias!